# How to fix DNN Web API returns 404 after upgrading to 9.2 from 9.0

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I had a website running DotNetNuke 9.0, after updating to 9.2 suddenly my API starts to return 404, nothing on the API changed, just the dnn framework.

I have tried to add  and clear cache, and restart the application, nothing worked so far.

Also checked the SEO URL Rewrite options and this is what I have:

**Do Not Rewrite URL Regular Expression**

```
/DesktopModules/|/Providers/|/LinkClick\.aspx|/profilepic\.ashx|
/DnnImageHandler\.ashx|/__browserLink/|/API/|/WebAPI/
```

**Do Not Redirect URL Regular Expression**

```
(\.axd)|/Rss\.aspx|/SiteMap\.aspx|\.ashx|/LinkClick\.aspx|/Providers/
|/DesktopModules/|ctl=MobilePreview|/ctl/MobilePreview|/API/|/WebAPI/
```

Currently I have the following RouteMapper:

```
using System;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("WebAPI", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new[] { "WebAPI" });
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of my API Controller

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class PingController : DnnApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Send()
        {
            var portalId = PortalController.GetEffectivePortalId(PortalSettings.PortalId);
            UserInfo user = PortalSettings.UserInfo;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ping on portal: " + PortalSettings.PortalId + " You are user: " + user.Username);
        }

        //Could be  [DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles = "Registered Users" )]
        [DnnAuthorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage SendAuth()
        {
            var portalId = PortalController.GetEffectivePortalId(PortalSettings.PortalId);
            UserInfo user = PortalSettings.UserInfo;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ping on portal: " + PortalSettings.PortalId + " You are user: " + user.Username);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct? What else can I check?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this exact same problem this week for a new open source community website I was launching for #oqtane ( http://www.oqtane.org ). For me the the problem ended up being related to a missing reference in my web.config file. I am not sure how the reference was removed ( probably by uninstalling a DNN module ) but the end result was that routing was no longer enabled which caused the jQuery service calls to the WebApi methods to fail with 404 errors. You should check your web.config file in the Modules area to ensure that the UrlRoutingModule is included:

```
<modules>
  ...
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  ...
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the input, I verified and I had the reference there. I ended up having it almost working... after a lot of effort I got it to work but the [DnnAuthorize] was telling me that the access was forbidden (which is expected but I was passing the right credentials...) I gave up and rollbacked to the previous version to get it working...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Event Log to see if there are errors?

The 9.0 to 9.2 upgrade may have exposed you to some deprecated stuff that was removed in the 9.2 release.  Checking for errors is possibly a quick way to see if that's what happened.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, within the website itself I can't get any logs, because it's not an actual error, it's just a 404 because it can't resolve the Router class, I can't see the actual machine logs, but within the plesk panel all i get is a 404 request. I've also made a clean install of dnn 9.2 on some ec2 instance and copied the rules for the rewrite. 

If I needed to look into some dlls which ones would be important for this? My guess is DotNetNuke.Web.dll